# aspx form textbox values to word.dot bookmark

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, office-2010

I was wondering if anyone had a quick solution to have a button click to pass values from aspx web form to a word.dot. I have a button that opens my template but i would like it to pass textbox.text to book marks in the word template

> e.g textbox1.text = bookmark.ID textbox2.text = bookmark.Fname
>   textbox3.text = bookmark.Lname textbox4.text = bookmark.Address ext...

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fPath = @"\\Server12\170912.dot";
    FileInfo myDoc = new FileInfo(fPath);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + myDoc.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myDoc.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(myDoc.FullName);
    Response.End();
  }
```

Thank you in advance as always

Comment: any one out there, could do with some help on this one plz...

Comment: Bookmarks have to point to some text... what are you bookmarking?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.bookmarks_members.aspx

Comment: the button basically opens a word template from an aspx web form that gets filled-in, some of that information from the form need to be placed on this template, so i want to use the bookmarks on the table for the data from the form to be placed, hope that makes sense

Comment: sorry it doesn't yet... do have bookmarks already and you want to change their name and title? or you want to put text at a location of a specific book mart? or you are trying to create a new bookmark?

Comment: lol ok I’ll try explaining better
I have a word document saved on network share, this document holds other information including some fields which are blank but have word bookmarks. The books in the word document are called IAID, FullName, Address ext... 
When a user click on the button on the webpage the aspx button opens my word document from my shared location and inserts the values from the webpage e.g textbox1 and textbox2 and textbox3 in the word document bookmark location.
e.g 
textbox1.text = bookmark.ID
textbox2.text = bookmark.fullname
textbox4.text = bookmark.Address 
ext...